# Stripe payment button for ReactJs with a simple Snippet Code

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have found a lot of repositories and examples about installing an Stripe complete checkout, but I cannot just use the simple Snippet code that Stripe offers for a product. How can I use that code on a page in my React Project? Here is the code. I just want to redirect the user to the Stripe checkout page for that product, I don't want to use my own formulary and I don't want either to collect data in my app. Thanks a lot.

```
<!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

<!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
<button
  style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
  id="checkout-button-price_1Heree568gerg54rtretrt"
  role="link"
  type="button"
>
  Checkout
</button>

<div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_t5tyutrytutruytyutyufake....');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1Heree568gerg54rtretrt');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      lineItems: [{price: 'price_1Heree568gerg54rtretrt', quantity: 1}],
      mode: 'subscription',
      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
      successUrl: 'https://myweb.com/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://myweb.com/canceled',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dedicated component for that. As stated in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including), I am using [StripeJS](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) to import it as a module.

```js
// npm install @stripe/stripe-js
import React from 'react';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const StripeButton = (props) => {
  const [stripeError, setStripeError] = React.useState(null);
  const [stripe, setStripe] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect( async () => {
    if (!stripe) {
      // Here, you can use some `props` instead of hardcoding the API key
      const stripeTmp = await loadStripe('pk_live_t5tyutrytutruytyutyufake....');
      setStripe(stripeTmp);
    }
  });
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Reset error holder
    setStripeError(null);

    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      // Here you can use another `prop` instead of hard coding it
      lineItems: [{price: 'price_1Heree568gerg54rtretrt', quantity: 1}],
      mode: 'subscription',
      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
      successUrl: 'https://myweb.com/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://myweb.com/canceled',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        setStripeError(result.error.message);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      { stripe ? (
          <button
            style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px ;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
            id="checkout-button-price_1Heree568gerg54rtretrt"
            role="link"
            type="button"
            onClick={ handleClick }
          >
            Checkout
          </button>
        ) : "Loading..."
      }
      { stripeError ? <div id="error-message">{ stripeError }</div> : null }
    </>
  )
}

export default StripeButton;
```

Comment: I can not use await: Parsing error: 'await' is only allowed within async functions. Also I have this error: × TypeError: stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function

Comment: Updated the answer adding a `useEffect` to avoid calling a function with `await` during render.

Comment: We can also avoid any `async`/`await` code by adding a `then` after `loadStripe`: `loadStripe('...').then( setStripe )`

Comment: I think the problem is here: stripe.redirectToCheckout

Comment: Please, provide any error message or what makes you think that.